# Sonarqube API - Getting quality gates by "name" value instead of Id

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

Is it possible to identify quality gates/projects by name, rather than ID? [Docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=2392167)

For example, the following curl will return the quality gate with ID of "806":

```
curl -u user:pass -X GET "<domain>/api/qualitygates/search?gateId=806"
```

However, I want to get the quality gate by name. Something like:

```
curl -u user:pass -X GET "<domain>/api/qualitygates/search?gateId=<NAME>"
```

`"gateID"` is required and requires an integer value so I can't replace this with "name".

I'm using version 4.5.5

**EDIT**:
I've found you can get quality gates by name by hitting the following endpoint:

> /api/qualitygates/show?name=

I now just need assistance to get a project by name

Comment: You have to create your own program using the result of /api/qualitygates/list as base. But please, first update your SonarQube environment to the latest LTS version.

Comment: I've found you can get quality gates by name with /api/qualitygates/show? name="

Just need to find out how to get project by name now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
curl -u user:pass -X GET "<domain>/api/qualitygates/select?projectKey=<NAME>&gateName=<GATE-NAME>"
```